# Python-telegram-bot syntax error for the line "_id_attrs: Tuple[Any, ...] = ()"

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have installed the python-telegram-bot package through pip and pip3 on ubuntu and tried to load it with:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
```

I then get:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/telegram/base.py", line 42

_id_attrs: Tuple[Any, ...] = ()
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get a similar error for the python 2.7 version. The "base.py" file has a line with "`_id_attrs:`", I've been using python for a while and never have seen a variable name followed by a colon.  What is meant to make this line readable to python.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to update your python version to at least 3.6. The syntax (from the error) is introduced in python 3.6 (check [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/)).

Also, It's clearly stated in [the library's Documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot#introduction) that you must use v3.6+.

> This library provides a pure Python interface for the Telegram Bot
> API. *`It's compatible with Python versions 3.6+.`* PTB might also work on
> PyPy, though there have been a lot of issues before. Hence, PyPy is
> not officially supported.

Comment: Thanx, I appreciate the help.